# Does nearby ferromagnetic material alter the flux vs current linearity of an "air core" solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Within my understanding, (a) for an isolated solenoid in a vacuum (or air) magnetic flux density inside the solenoid is a perfectly linear function of solenoid current; and (b) in significantly permeable materials, flux density **B** is a highly nonlinear function of field strength.

When a structure of permeable material is *outside* the solenoid's windings, does its nonlinear flux characteristic impair the linearity of **B** vs current *inside* the solenoid, however slightly?  For visualization, I imagine the solenoid inside a coaxial ferromagnetic cylinder.

My intuition is that the effect of external flux nonlinearity with respect to current will be much attenuated inside the solenoid, but will nonetheless spoil the linearity of internal flux density

I also welcome pointers toward how to set up analysis of such a system, even as a simple approximation.

*Addendum*

A more elementary question:

Suppose that the only **H** field is produced by current in an "air core" solenoid.  If adding or removing an object exterior to the solenoid alters the **B** field near that object, does that change have a finite effect on flux density in the solenoid's interior?

It seems to me that if the answer is "yes," then the presence of exterior ferromagnetic material must render the interior flux density a nonlinear function of current.

Comment: Of course as you mention, compared with material *inside* the windings, the influence will be less, but still non-zero for material outside the windings. Whether this will "spoil" the linearity depends on how much linearity you need for the specific application.

Comment: A magnet cannot be "more" nonlinear than being a permanent one whose definition being that its magnetization is independent of any amount of external field. So the field of a coil cannot be linearly dependent on its current if there is, in principle, anywhere in space an ideal permanent magnet. Of course, there are no "ideal" permanent magnets and even if their were they could be sufficiently small at far away distances, so...

Comment: look up "metal detector" on google.

Comment: hyportnex - The field of a permanent magnet would combine with the solenoid's field, adding a bias or offset.  I don't see how that in itself would change the linear dependence of flux density on solenoid current.

Comment: niels nielsen - Metal detectors use alternating magnetic fields to induce eddy currents in external metal objects.  My question is about the steady-state field of a solenoid at various steady currents.